# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException In Simon Game, Can't Figure Out Why

Tags: input

I'm pretty new to Java, but not OOP in general. I'm working on the classic Simon game where the user follows an increasing sequence of a randomly generated pattern (numbers really) for my Java class. I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
at Simon.generateSequence(Simon.java:58)
at Simon.<init>(Simon.java:23)
```

I can't figure out how to fix this. It doesn't look like I'm calling more elements than are in the array. Here's the code:

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Simon extends Program implements ActionListener
{
private int array[];
private int currentSeqLength;
private int usersInput;


public Simon()
{
    //Initialize Class Values
    array = new int[20];
    currentSeqLength = 1;
    usersInput = 0;

    generateSequence();

    while(currentSeqLength <= array.length)
    {
        playSequence();

        //Wait For User's Input Here, Assign To Variable
        //usersInput = 

        if (pushButton(usersInput)== true)
        {

            currentSeqLength++;
        }

        else
        {
            gameOverMessage();
            break;

            //Reset Variables:

        }

    }


}

public void generateSequence()
{

    //Fill Array With Random Numbers
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*4);

    }


}

public void setLength(int length)
{
    //Set Current Length To Size Of Given Argument
    currentSeqLength = length;

}

int getLength()
{
    return currentSeqLength;

}

int[] playSequence()
{
    //Print Out The Current Sequence

    //New Local Array To Return
    int newArray[]= new int[currentSeqLength];


    //Repeat As Many Times As Value Of currentSeqLength
    for(int i = 0; i <= currentSeqLength ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[i]);

        //Return an array of int's to the player. 
        newArray[i] = array[i];

    }

    return newArray;
}

boolean pushButton(int usersInput)
{
    //Given A Button Press (0-3), Return Whether That Was The 
        //Correct Button To Play At The Moment

    if (usersInput == array[currentSeqLength])
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }


}

boolean isTurnOver()
{
    //If Current Sequence Length Matches Or Exceeds Value Of 
        //Array Element In Location Of Current Sequence Length

    if (currentSeqLength >= array[currentSeqLength])
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

//Not Needed?
boolean isGameOver()
{
    if (pushButton(usersInput) == false)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

String gameOverMessage()
{
    return "Game Over";
}

/*public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    int input;


}
*/
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*4);

    }
```

you are looping from 0 to 20. 20 is the length of the array, 21 is the number of iterations this for loop will do.

replace <= with <.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but now I'm getting the same exception at playSequence(). I took out the '=' there too, but it looks like there's something going on with line 92, where:

    newArray[i] = array[i];

Comment: Learning to interpret compiler error messages is as vital skill as learning to use debug tools. Any specific error messages?

Comment: Yes, it's pointing to line 92, where that^ piece of code is:  at Simon.<init>(Simon.java:23)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Simon.playSequence(Simon.java:92)
 at Simon.<init>(Simon.java:27)

Comment: Did you modify that for loop comparison to less than operator as well? Because you will get the array out of bounds exception without doubt. Do you have a debugger at hand?

Comment: Yes, I did take that "=" out of the 'for' loop in playSequence as well, but it looks like there's something up with the newArray[i]= array[i] on line 92, which is in the body of that 'for' loop. Maybe there is something wrong with the logic? I'm using BlueJ, and not exactly sure if there is a debugger in there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To set a breakpoint, click in the breakpoint area to the left of the text in the editor. Then inspect the values of the arrays, their lengths, the i variable while running in debug.